# Laptop is slow with Ryzen 7 4700u?

Tags: 20.04, amd-ryzen

I bought a HP ProBook 455 G7 as a new working laptop with the following hardware:

- 16 GB DDR4 3200 MHz
- Ryzen 7 4700U Processor
- SSD M.2 512 GB
- AMD Vega 7 Mobile Graphic Card

I want to use the laptop for programming, but its very slow. The CPU quickly rushes to 350 - 425% percent when opening PHPStorm as you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E17tHiruHJY&feature=youtu.be). Also just when I code normally and open a new file, the laptop lags.

Same problem when using normal websites. I switched from using Firefox to Chrome to improve website performance, but it still slow. Sometimes when opening a merge request view in GitLab or opening a tool like Asana in my browser my PC lags or even crashes and I have to restart. [Here](https://youtu.be/-VtL6AaCP8c) you can see how I browse immobilienscout24.de in Chrome but its very sluggish. Pressing the "next" icon often has to wait or skips images, and the CPU goes almost instantly to 100%.

I am very buffed that I have these kinds of performance issues with a Laptop equipped with the above hardware. Is Ubuntu 20.04 not compatible with Ryzen 7? Do I need to install any special drivers?

I am also considering buying another laptop, however, before I do so, I would need to know what the bottleneck is with my current setup. Its hard to imagine for me that the CPU is the problem, because I read that Ryzen 7 4700U even outperforms i7-1065G7 in benchmark.

Comment: Try the 5.8 kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`. It has a lot of improvements for new Ryzen integrated GPUs.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am on kernel 5.11.3 and installed hwe - or would you recommend to downgrade to 5.8? Starting PHPStorm and the immoscout24 have not changed in their performance. I will see if it improves for the other regular tasks. Do you think Intel processers have better support from Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't buy this CPU yet. The 5.4 could be a problem. 5.11 should be good, but the 5.8 is worth testing.

Comment: Is your motherboard/ssd firmware up to date?  Check at the vendor's site for updates regularly. Have you applied any kernel options, like acpi=0, which may fix some problems, but may introduce others.

Comment: @ubfan1 I contacted AMD they told me, there is no official support for Ubuntu for Ryzon 7 4700u. Thus, I sold that laptop again and bought a laptop with officail Ubuntu support.

Answer (score 1):

It also happened to me on a Ryzen 4700u. I discovered that with stock kernel embedded graphics don't work. You need at least a 5.8 kernel. But in order to get headsets sound working you will also need to install a 5.9 kernel. To solve that I installed mainline application and I selected the latest 5.9 kernel.

Comment: I am using 5.11 kernel, but its still hangs when using some complex webapplications in mutliple tabs. Not sure if its because of the graphic card. I will probably buy a new one soon