# Install graphic driver for AMD Ryzen 7 4700U APU with Renoir Vega 10 Graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I have bought this [laptop](https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c06543048.pdf) from HP.

From the technical specifications document I found that it contains AMD Ryzen 7 4700U APU with Renoir Vega 10 Graphics (Page 4) and (Page 5) AMD Radeon Graphics.

I have problems finding a graphic driver for this device: https://www.amd.com/en/support what is the correct one? Is it this:
[image]

Not sure if a mobile processor can be build in a laptop. Also when I click on downloads, there is only a Windows driver givien.

Does there exists a Ubuntu graphic driver for my card? I experience extreme performance problems and hope a graphic driver could help.

Comment: I think that you need this one: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45 BTW, Did you get the graphic card working? I installed the drivers (downgrading the kernel 5.4 before because in 5.8 give me an installation error ) but when loading the module the laptop is frozen.

Comment: @angelcervera I wrote to AMD support service. They told me that they do not support AMD Ryzen 7 4700U APU with Renoir Vega 10 Graphics for Ubuntu. I can use my laptop, but  it crashes from time to time, especially when I have to many tabs open.  I have ordered now a new Laptop from dell with intel processer. It cost twice as much as the HP, but at least they offer support for Ubuntu. I will sell the HP laptop, very frustrating experience.

Comment: Mine is a Lenovo ThinkPad L14 G1. I updated the BIOS and all is working fine. No problems booting, Detecting and using the latest AMD Rodeon driver, WIFI, Webcam, etc... Ubunutu distro automatically uses the right drivers. It was not necessary, but I installed ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers to have latest mesa versions as well.

Comment: @angelcervera glad you got it working. I tried everything, from upgrading bios, kernel, followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303500/laptop-is-slow-with-ryzen-7-4700u). Its not working. However, I learned to value the Linux support from companies like Dell.

Comment: Yes, I'm a little bit disappointed with Lenovo's support because of the same reason.